# Slider ui smooth sticking point?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a slider and I need him to move smoothly, but stuck at certain points. Now he is clumsy moves from point to point. I also need smooth movement, how to achieve it?

```
$('#slider').slider({
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 15,
  animate: 1100,
});
```

that's the whole code.
I need to "step" is preserved, but the motion was flowing to it

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.